# Which try-squares have acceptable accuracy?

Tags: measurement

The question is about specific producs or lines by brands.
This is meant for hobbyist use - but if there just isn't anything in a roughly "hobbyist price range", then so be it.

I attempt to make this not "primarily opinion based" by defining what I find *not* acceptable accuracy.

I am speaking of try squares with a metric ruler, and a handle with greater thickness than the ruler, so you can hold it against a piece of wood's side while the ruler is going over the side, to have the ruler at a perfect right angle to the work piece's edge.

Any of such instruments I ever bought at Germany's ~ equivalents of a "Home Depot" is basically an unusable toy:

- Say it's ruler is 25cm long.
- The supposed right angle is off
- so that at its end, it will be several millimeters off on the perpendicular axis, and at its half maybe ~ 2 mm.
- The ruler is not perfectly positioned at the start at the handle, all the measurements will be ~ 1/2mm off (plus offset due to the bad right angle)
- And it's slightly different on the flip side - ruler markings on both sides are not perfectly aligned.

Are there products which are significantly better than that?

Comment: If the markings are not aligned take back that is a manufacturing defect.True machinist tools are extremely accurate but fairly expensive. Some reasonably priced are quite accurate (Empire last ones  bought) good framing squares are very accurate but clumsy in my opinion. With few exception 1/64 in 10" will not make a difference as wood moves.

Comment: *"The question is about specific producs or lines by brands."* This is a shopping question, which I'm afraid are off-topic here. However, general piece of advice when buying modern try squares intended for carpentry or woodworking is to buy in person and test for square (both on inside and outside edges of the blade). Many brands, even some previously well-regarded ones, no longer produce squares that are uniformly accurate so you *must* check accuracy before you buy.

Comment: If this question can be re-worded so that instead of asking _what_ product to buy, but rather _how_ to evaluate and (possibly) validate to some extent the many budget precision measure and markup tools out there, then maybe this can be salvaged. It could even the source of a wiki style entry. (I'm prompted to comment because I just spent a week reviewing my motley collection of measure/markup tools trying to determine which ones were "good enough". So I could say what _I've_ done...)

Comment: PW has a nice selection of articles that would be hard to beat, though someone could summarize appropriately in one or more Q&A: https://www.popularwoodworking.com/marking-and-measuring/ and specifically: https://www.popularwoodworking.com/tag/precision-instruments/

Comment: Sorry I ran out of room and forgot to post a second Comment yesterday, if you can wait until they come in as weekly specials you can buy squares from Lidl or Aldi! Even though they are lightly constructed from aluminium they can be accurate (but you must check). In the meantime, you can make a square from wood, no measurable error is easily achievable in any workshop if you have one straight edge to work from (the factory edge of MDF or plywood will usually be straight enough) and then use the 3-4-5 rule (Pythagoras) for layout. There are numerous articles on making various styles online.

Comment: @Graphus, I'm looking at larger try-squares right now because that is a gap in my tooling, and, coincidentally, was considering just making one out of some hardwood I have that I'm cutting down for mitre "bars" anyway. If I'm not paying for ANSI standard devices I may as well go shop-made.

Comment: Hrm "shopping question", makes sens, not sure ATM how to rephrase that, not much time now to think about, I'll try to remember on the weekend if that suffices.
IIRC on stackoverflow, questions about (software) tools directly related to programming are (or were?) allowed, so I had guessed it's similar for tools here.
The thing is... if I ask about ways how to identify good tools, I still wouldn't get an answer where the heck I will find them, I'd basically need to buy lots of stuff and try and send back...

Comment: Shopping enquiries had to be disabled I think because of the risk of shilling & spam Questions where the asker would then Answer themselves in order to post a product link. Recommendations of tools/products/services spontaneously within Answers is allowed but one can't ask specifically is A, B or C the better buy. Anyway don't worry about that for now, if you have many things you would like to ask about a conventional forum would be a better venue, so you can engage with responders, you and they can ask follow-on questions as needed, get clarifications, talk about budget etc. etc. [contd]

Comment: SE is just not built for that kind of thing. Plus there aren't enough active members willing to provide Answers! Forums work much better for this and can have **far** larger active memberships, dozens to hundreds of people..... instead of only a handful here.

Comment: Can you recommend a forum for this topic?

Comment: @user1847129 You could try reddit or some traditional woodworking forums like the ones that show up at the top of this google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=woodworking+forum